# How to save details users visit pages to SQL in MVC 4 application?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider

I have a basic mvc 4 application.Is there any way for save user visits on every page to SQL ? 
I want save username,visited_url,visit_time to SQL.

I did not found any document for that. Where I need to start?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Action Filters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can have CustomAttribute(which makes the DB call and save the values) to the every controller if you want to save the details for every action method in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an custom Action Filter for Pre-Action  or Post-Action when you will implement your code to save your requirements on the database. You will probably use by overriding OnActionExecuting and OnActionExecuted.